# How do I check whether a player is holding the SPACE key or pressing it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, keyboard

I want to bind 2 attack styles to the same key, and switch between them based on whether or not the player is holding it or just pressing.

```
void Attack()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            //do something
        }

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            //do something different
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Input.GetKeyDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) returns true during the frame the user starts pressing down the key identified by name, while [Input.GetKey](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) returns true while the user holds down the key identified by name.
Seems you need to give Input.GetKey a try.